# Get the title from a URL in the same domain 

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

It's very common to load partial content of a website using

```
$('#where').load('page.php #what');
```

But how can I update the title of the current document according to the page.php title?

I need to do this in javascript:

```
$url = "http://www.mywebiste.com/page.php";
$file = file_get_contents($url);

if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i",$file,$result)
print "The title of $url is <b>$result[1]</b>";
else
print "The page doesn't have a title tag";
```

It it possible?

Comment: You can't via JS, it's a security risk.

Comment: @zzzzBov: only if it's on another site, which has not been clarified in the question one way or another.

Comment: @Jordan, i see `http://www.google.com/` as the url being requested, but you're right, OP needs to read about the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `get`

```
$.get('page.php', function(data){
     var the_page_loaded = $(data);
     document.title = $('title', the_page_loaded).text();
     $('#where').html($('#what', the_page_loaded)); //do the load as you wanted
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in jQuery it would be relatively simple:

```
$.get('page.php', function(data) {
    alert($(data).find('title').text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the get method is probably the best idea, but that's already been suggested, so as an alternative you could put the title of the new page in the title or even a data tag of the link (or other element) I assume you are clicking to load the new content.

```
<a href="page.php" title="Load page.php" data-title="This is the new page title">Load page.php</a>
```

or

```
<a href="page.php" title="This is the new page title">Load page.php</a>
```